# Less compiling on FTP server

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, ftp, less

I'm working on a project directly on a FTP server (normally I work locally). I use Visual studio to edit and compile my LESS files. When the LESS file is compiled to css, the site wont' update to the newest css rules. When I manually save the css file the changes become visible.

Does anybody know what the issue is here? I haven't got a clue.

Comment: It could be something as simple as clearing your cache.

Comment: How do you compile the less file? I'm not sure how Visual Studio but perhaps it doesn't upload the compiled file to the server automatically.

Comment: Visual Studio needs the Web essentials plugin to compile the less file. WE uses NodeJS to run the compiler.